# How to merge dictionaries and group by value in python?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python like this:

```
{
'k1': 'AAB',
'k2': 'AAB',
'k3': 'ABA',
'k4': 'AAB',
'k5': 'A--',
'k6': 'AB-',
'k7': 'BB-',
'k8': 'B--',
'k9': 'B-B',
'k10': '--C',
}
```

Where '-' is a wildcard. And I want to merge them by grouping by key

```
{
'k1, k2, k4, [k5]' : 'AAB',
'k3, (k6), [k5]' : 'ABA',
'{k7, k8, k9}' : 'B--',
'{k10}' : '--C',
}
```

The items with wildcards should be between parentheses when it matches with only one possible combination (ie. k6), and between brackets when it matches more than one combination (ie. k5). Also, when values with wildcards do not match any other full elements without wildcards), they should be between braces, and the value should be the one with more wildcards.

I have managed to compare string with wildcards using regex:

```
# v1 and v2 are the values to compare
v1_reg = v1.replace("-","?")
cont = 0
for s in v2:
    if s == "-":
        v1_reg = v1_reg[:cont] + "?" + v1_reg[cont+1:]
    cont += 1
if(fnmatch(v2, v1_reg)):
   ##THERE'S A MATCH
```

I still did not find a way to make the grouping.

Comment: i think you mean group by value.

Comment: Why does `k5` match `ABA`?

Comment: yes, it was my mistake, updated

Comment: how many characters a wildcard would match?

Comment: The suggested solution is the only possible? Why? Sorry if it is a dummy question...

Comment: I did not suggest any solution at all, only a part of it

Comment: why you have an item for `B--` but not for `A--` ?

Comment: because A-- matches with AAB and ABA, so when you have a match you put the item with the wildcard in it, but when you do not have a match, you merge items with wildcards together, leaving the one with more '-' as the value

Comment: May be it better use something like a tree... but why would you do that? A trivial solution is enough simple, counting all possible wildcard.

Comment: well I'm not able to find a trivial solution, or at least hints about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code will do matching, and grouping as required, and as bonus, it will filter the wildcards match nothing. i've implemented the comparison between `TransUnit` for you too. use it to see whether two `TransUnit`s are equal or one is more general. check it yourself, and see how it works:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Char:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self._c = c

    def match(self, obj): return obj.match_c(self._c)

    def match_c(self, cc):
        return self._c == cc

    def match_w(self): return True


class WildCard:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def match(self, obj): return obj.match_w()

    def match_c(self, cc): return True

    def match_w(self): return True


class TransUnit(object):
    def __init__(self, key, s):
        self._val = s
        self._arr = [WildCard() if c == '-' else Char(c) for c in s]
        self._key = key
        self._matches = 0
        self._has_wildcard = any(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, WildCard), self._arr))

    @property
    def has_wildcard(self): return self._has_wildcard

    @property
    def val(self): return self._val

    def found_match(self): self._matches += 1

    def match(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, str):
            return TransUnit(None, obj).match_arr(self._arr)
        return obj.match_arr(self._arr)

    def match_arr(self, arr):
        if len(self._arr) != len(arr): return False
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            if not self._arr[i].match(arr[i]):
                return False
        return True

    def compare(self, obj):
        return -obj.compare_arr(self._arr)

    def compare_arr(self, arr):
        if not self.match_arr(arr): raise Exception()
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            if not isinstance(self._arr[i], WildCard) and isinstance(arr[i], WildCard):
                return -1
            elif not isinstance(arr[i], WildCard) and isinstance(self._arr[i], WildCard):
                return 1
        return 0

    def __str__(self):
        if self._has_wildcard:
            if self._matches <= 1:
                return '(' + self._key + ')'
            else:
                return '[' + self._key + ']'
        else:
            return self._key

    __repr__ = __str__


def group(dct):
    trans = [TransUnit(k, dct[k]) for k in dct]
    wilds = [t for t in trans if t.has_wildcard]
    nonwilds = [t for t in trans if not t.has_wildcard]
    grouper = defaultdict(list)
    for n in nonwilds:
        grouper[n.val].append(n)

    notmatched = []
    for w in wilds:
        matched = False
        for k, lst in grouper.items():
            if w.match(k):
                w.found_match()
                lst.append(w)
                matched = True
        if not matched:
            notmatched.append(w)

    return (grouper, notmatched)
```

test:

```
>>> group({
'k1': 'AAB',
'k2': 'AAB',
'k3': 'ABA',
'k4': 'AAB',
'k5': 'A--',
'k6': 'AB-',
'k7': 'BB-',
'k8': 'B--',
'k9': 'B-B',
})
(defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'ABA': [k3, (k6), [k5]], 'AAB': [k2, k1, k4, [k5]]}), [(k7), (k9), (k8)])
```

Comment: well, your solution is way more professional that the one I was trying to obtain. Let me take a look and I'll be back

Comment: It is a very clean solution, thank you. Now, I'm trying to group the notmatched elements with themselves

Comment: @JuanmaCrescente that's easy too. a hint: view the ones have no matches as nodes, then edge between each pair of nodes means nodes match each other. now what you have to do is to see how many pieces this graph gets divided into, and put nodes in each piece together.

Comment: both solutions are great IMO, I marked this as the accepted answer since it was the first one

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:*** I have modified this to your new specifications.

Maybe a bit overkill. But this works. (Excuse the horrible variable names)
It's not the most efficient method, but it follows logical steps (to me at least) Hopefully this will do what you need it to, but you should use this as a guideline and improve upon it to meet your specific needs.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint
from re import match

## Class to help display the results as you want
class Organizer():

    def __getitem__(self):
        return Organizer()

    def __init__(self):
        self.normal = []
        self.parens = []
        self.brackets = []
        self.fancy = []

    def __str__(self):
        ret = ''
        for group, a, z in [(self.normal, '', ''),
                            (self.parens, '(', ')'),
                            (self.brackets, '[', ']'),
                            (self.fancy, '{', '}')]:
            if group:  # If there is something to format
                ret += self._frmt(group, a, z)
        return ret.strip(', ')  # Remove extra formatting.

    def _frmt(self, group, a, z):
        return ', {}{}{}'.format(a, ', '.join(sorted(group)), z)

## Function that does what you want.
def match_to_wildcards(key_value_pairs):
    values_as_keys, partial = defaultdict(Organizer), {}
    # Prepare the initial groups.
    for key, value in key_value_pairs.items():
        if '-' in value:
            partial[key] = value
        else:
            values_as_keys[value].normal.append(key)
    # Clean up the partial matches.
    partial_matches = {k: [f for f in values_as_keys if match(v.replace('-', '.'), f)] for k, v in partial.items()}
    for key, values in partial_matches.items():
        if not values:
            continue
        for value in values:
            if len(values) > 1:
                values_as_keys[value].brackets.append(key)
            else:
                values_as_keys[value].parens.append(key)
            if key in partial:
                partial.pop(key)
    # Filter the last unmatched items.
    combined_unmatched = {u: [v for v in partial.values() if match(u.replace('-', '.'), v)] for u in partial.values()}
    need_to_be_rearranged = {k: [(p, p.count('-')) for p, j in combined_unmatched.items() if k in j] for k, v in combined_unmatched.items() if len(v) == 1}
    # Sort the last unmatched items.
    for key, value in partial.items():
        if value in need_to_be_rearranged:
            value_key = max(need_to_be_rearranged[value], key=itemgetter(1))[0]
            values_as_keys[value_key].fancy.append(key)
        else:
            values_as_keys[value].fancy.append(key)
    # Return the results, format them.
    return {str(v): k for k, v in values_as_keys.items()}
```

Now run the code with your data.

```
## Test
data_set = {
    'k1': 'AAB',
    'k2': 'AAB',
    'k3': 'ABA',
    'k4': 'AAB',
    'k5': 'A--',
    'k6': 'AB-',
    'k7': 'BB-',
    'k8': 'B--',
    'k9': 'B-B',
    'k10': '--C'
}
pprint(match_to_wildcards(data_set))
# {'k1, k2, k4, [k5]': 'AAB',
#  'k3, (k6), [k5]': 'ABA',
#  '{k10}': '--C',
#  '{k7, k8, k9}': 'B--'}
```

Comment: Thanks. I realize that k9 should match k8 and k7, and the value should be B--, according to the specification.

Comment: @JuanmaCrescente Check the edit. I hope you like it.